# Application logs collected in Datadog are replicated

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, datadog

I have a Java/Spring-Boot container application running on Amazon ECS with EC2 as the underlying service for the container cluster. A datadog-agent container (v7.18.1-jmx) is also running within the cluster to feed the logs/metrics back to datadog servers. The logs are flowing through to the datadog webapp as expected but I see the same log line 3 times in the UI. The following environment variables have been set -

```
DD_API_KEY=<API-KEY>
DD_APM_ENABLED=true
DD_APM_ENV=dev
DD_APM_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC=true
DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC=true
DD_DOGSTATSD_ORIGIN_DETECTION=true
DD_DOGSTATSD_TAGS=["env:dev"]
DD_LOG_LEVEL=error
DD_LOGS_CONFIG_COMPRESSION_LEVEL=1
DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_COMPRESSION=true
DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL=true
DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_HTTP=true
DD_LOGS_ENABLED=true
DD_TAGS=environment:dev
DD_URL=<Datadog-url>
```

Following mount points are present in the datadog-agent container definition in ECS -

```
Container Path            Source Volume     Read only

/var/run/docker.sock      docker_sock       true
/host/proc/               proc              true
/host/sys/fs/cgroup       cgroup            true
/opt/datadog-agent/run    pointdir           
/etc/passwd               passwd            true
```

I tried replicating this by setting up the application and the datadog-agent on my Docker Desktop and there seems to be no issue with that setup. Is it happening because the same log content is getting captured at multiple mount points? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was unrelated to Datadog or Docker. It was an issue with how log4j was configured in the application. There were multiple appenders getting initialized programatically which led to this problem.